# Delphi: Balloon Form with fsStayOnTop not working in Win7

Tags: forms, delphi, window, balloon, topmost

I have an application that uses my own balloon form.
This is a non-bordered, fsStayOnTop kind form.

I show it with this code:

```
ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
Visible := True;
```

Today I realized that if I activate another application then the balloon is not appearing!
So it is loosing it's stay on top style.

Environment:
Win7/x64
Delphi 6 Professional

What I can do with it?

Thanks:
   dd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What worked for me in the past when struggling with stay-on-top forms:

```
Form := TMyForm.Create(Self);
Application.NormalizeTopMosts;
SetWindowPos(Form.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             SWP_NOACTIVATE + SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE);
Form.Show;
```

Try this instead of your `ShowWindow` call. This stays on top of *all* windows (do you really want this?). Also it feelds kind of hacky because it omits the `RestoreTopMosts` call which the documentation says we should call (so other stay-on-top windows in your application will be affected). So there might be a better solution.

Comment: Don't combine flags using `+`. You need to use `or`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution and it did not work on a secondary form. I believe it will work on a main form, but not on a secondary form. However, I did find a solution that works for a secondary form, which sounds like what the original poster wanted, as a "balloon form" is typically a pop-up.

Put this in the "Form B" OnCreate event:

**FormStyle:= fsStayOnTop;**

but that alone isn't enough...

Drag a **TApplicationEvents** onto your "Form B"

In the **OnDeactivate** event for **ApplicationEvents1**, add the following:

**SetForegroundWindow(Handle);**

I keep an eye on a small status window while my main form is crunching data out of site. Works beautifully!